# What is the interpretation of Nirukta-1:20?

Tags: scripture, vedas, interpretation

> Nirukta-1:20
>
> sākṣāt kṛta dharmāṇa ṛṣayo babhūvuḥ
> te avarebhyo asākṣāt kṛta dharmabhya upadeśena mantrānt samprāduḥ
> Upadeśāya glāyanto.avare bilma grahanāya imam grantham samāmnāsiṣur vedaṃsa va veda aṅgāni ca
>
> The Rishis are the one who had direct vision of the truth. For the sake of the inferior people who were not endowed with the vision, they gave these mantras as teachings. This is the Veda and Vedangas.

What is the meaning of "mantra" here? I mean which mantra, vedic mantras or other mantra the are non vedic?

And is this verse saying that vedic mantras are authored by humans(**enlightened rishies**).

Comment: Your question self-answers itself. *"For the sake of the inferior people"*. We all are the inferior people (devoid of any spiritual vision). Further, ***"This is the Veda and Vedangas."*** - the collection of all verses (mantras) that you ask about, no specific mantra. Vedas are either authorless (or proceeds from the Supreme God), rishies are just their seers (*drishtas*).

Comment: 'mantra' is how 'words' are referred to in Sanskrit.

Comment: @Vivikta can you answer it